# Are $T,T^2$ compact operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

$T:l_2\to l_2$ is defined by $T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(0,x_1,0,x_3,0,x_5,\dots)$ we need to find whether $T, T^2$ are compact or not. [I see here the definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtAPx.png)
of compact operator but I'm not able to apply. Could anyone give me hints?

$T^2(x_1,x_2,\dots)=T(0,x_1,0,x_3,0\dots)=(0,0,0,\dots)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly $T^2$ is compact. But $T$ isn't, because the range of the unit ball contains $S:=\{e_{2k+1},k\geqslant 0\}$ (where $e_j$ are classical canonical Hilbert basis). The set $S$ is not compact for the same reason as the unit ball isn't.

Comment: I want to see a non trivial example where $T$ is compact using image of unit ball definition. Could you ...?

Comment: @SenoreBunuel If you want to use only image of unit ball definition, the simplest example probably is the operator $T \in \mathcal L( L^p )$, $1 \leq p < \infty$ s.t. $( T a )_n = \lambda_n a_n$, where $\lambda = \{\lambda_n\} \subseteq \mathbb K$ ($\mathbb K$ is our field), that turns out to be compact iff $\lambda \in c_0$. ($c_0 \subset \ell^\infty$ of all sequences which converge to $0$, $\mathcal L( L^P)$ is the (Banach) space of bounded operators on $L^p$.)